# Distributed performance monitor that dynamically uses available Win32_Perf counters

Tags: windows-10, system-monitor

Performance Monitor is looking pretty janky nowadays

[image]

Awful, dated UI.  I'm looking for any alternatives.  It's important that the alternative allows me **to select from the available performance counters on the current machine or on machines on the network**.  That means nothing that only tracks a few of the common ones, like the performance tab of Task Manager.

I've gone hunting a few times, but I haven't bagged anything...

Comment: What functions do you to monitor? ie. CPU, Memory, Network, etc. Also, is free needed or can it be commercial?

Comment: Free or commercial, looking for a complete replacement.  As for your second question, *"It's important that the alternative allows me to select from the available performance counters on the current machine or on machines on the network."* that means no BS CPU/IO widget crap.  Full on replacement.

Comment: Please list all of the performance counters that must be available (for both host and remote).

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I did.  All of them.  A performance counter replacement is worthless if it doesn't allow you to monitor any of the available counters on the box.  Notice the bold text.  There are a host of standard counters, but the whole list depends entirely on the machine's configuration and installed applications.  The list of counters available on a machine is fully discoverable to any application that isn't crap.

Comment: @Will: I am learning something new here, would you mind telling me the name of the discovery protocol used for that purpose? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul depends on what the application is written in.  You might use WMI to discover available counters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(v=vs.85).aspx I write C#, so I would use the PerformanceCounterCategory class to get categories, then enumerate the counters in each category. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a65ekyd(v=vs.110).aspx This is all standard stuff that a decently written application can handle. Crappy applications are just going to expose the low hanging fruit (disk IO, CPU, etc) without attempting to discover all available counters.

Comment: Interesting! Last thing, please add to your question what details the app shown in the screenshot are bad, be very specific rather than just saying "janky".

Comment: Look, I don't want to list everything about it that I don't like.  That might appear to disqualify alternatives.  If I say I don't like feature X, and an alternative PM application Foo has that same feature, that doesn't mean "don't suggest Foo, because it has X".  I'd look at the entirety of Foo and weigh all of its positives and negatives.  Janky is slang for junky, not good, it's got issues, I'm tired of it, blah.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind the tool and I am long time windows expert :-)

Check the [Syskit](http://www.syskit.com) it can connect to the server and extract info about the performance of every component of the servers. The application is commercial but mention you read about it on the super user and mention me so I will tell guys to provide good discount :-)

Comment: A good discount on what? Could you please include the "official price tag"? :)

Comment: Please describe how it can use all available Win32_Perf counters, as it is a central part of the question. Also, screenshots and list price, thanks!

Comment: The official price tag is $299 per server, but the price drops with the volume. I wanted to say that you mention when requesting price that you saw this on the stack exchange and we will include extra discount.
The application connects directly to the windows performance counters library and you can extra the numbers from any counter that is in the Windows Performance counters.Screenshot are here: https://www.syskit.com/features/server-performance-monitoring/

Comment: Hi. Would you mind looking at my question? I had a look at the Syskit website, but I was not able to find the feature I'm looking for.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45367/viewer-for-performance-monitor-logs