# Viewer for Performance Monitor logs

Tags: windows, debugging

I have some huge Microsoft Performance Monitor logs capturing data over several days. While I was quite happy viewing smaller logs, I now find that Performance Monitor is not good at zooming and scrolling in such huge amount of data.

I'm looking for

- a program that can read Performance Monitor logs (.BLG files)
- basically the capabilities of Performance Monitor, but
- does not need to be able to record performance data
- has nice/better scrolling and zooming capabilities, especially zoom out (the minus loupe) must be available.
- works on Windows

Basically I'm looking for a gratis tool, but since I doubt there are many, please also offer commercial tools of any price.